# How do i get a view frames axis directions given a camera's direction vector?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems

Say I have some custom view orientation in which the global coordinate frame looks like the picture below with no axis aligned to the edges of the computer monitors screen:

[image: xyz-global]

Say the direction vector from the origin away from the camera (away from you) is given by this vector:

Vector (-0.3159932494163513, 0.5070327520370483, -0.8019139766693115)

(Note that i am working in orthographic projections if that matters.)

But this is only one direction vector perpendicular to the computers monitor.

How would I get the direction vector parallel to the top (or bottom) edge of the monitor (i.e, the horizontal direction)?
Likewise, how would i get the direction vector parallel to the left (or right) side edge of the monitor (i.e, the vertical direction)?

Do i have enough information to find the rest of this frames axis directions?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The horizontal and vertical screen axes are gotten by a different method mentioned in the comments. They are black in color.

Amd posted a method and gave his values for u and v for the camera direction I provided. These are the blue lines.

[image: amd's u and v lines in blue]

I did the steps described by amd and projected my own points then read off the values. These gave the following red lines.

[image: Mark's u and v lines in red]

Something is off!

There is not enough information to find the remain two axis directions that are parallel to edges of the monitor. One cannot position the XYZ-frame to the monitor just by moving one of it's axis in a parallel direction to the view direction through the origin. The moved XYZ-frame can still take any orientation around it's view directed axis. More information is needed to fix it's orientation.

Comment: Well, the obvious possibilities are that you’re not projecting $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ correctly, or that “up” for the camera doesn’t correspond to “up” on screen.

Comment: Nope. Everything checks out.

Answer (score 2):

*The short answer:* Let $O$ be the screen image of the world-coordinate origin, so that we have $X-O=(x_h,x_v)$, $Y-O=(y_h,y_v)$ and $Z-O=(z_h,z_v)$ for the unit world-coordinate axis vectors in screen coordinates. Then the world coordinates of the direction vectors for the edges of the screen are simply $(x_h,y_h,z_h)$ and $(x_v,y_v,z_v)$.

---

Orthographic (a.k.a. orthogonal) projection makes this fairly easy to compute. This projects onto some plane perpendicular to the camera’s axis $\mathbf n$, which for the purposes of this problem we can take as passing through the origin. The projection can be represented as a change of basis from the global $xyz$ coordinate system to the camera’s $x'y'z'$ coordinate system, which is accomplished with a rotation, and then projecting orthogonally onto some plane perpendicular to the camera’s axis—the $z'$-axis. This projection amounts to deleting the $z'$ coordinate. There’s also a translation involved since the origin of the viewport coordinate system isn’t necessarily at the point that corresponds to the camera’s axis, but I’ll suppress this aspect of the projection since it has no effect on what you’re trying to compute.

Since orthographic projection is parallel to the camera’s axis, the actual location of the image plane is irrelevant—only its attitude, i.e., the camera’s orientation, matters. In terms of this orientation, which can be described via pitch, yaw and roll from some standard orientation, the unit vector $\mathbf n$ that gives the camera’s facing takes care of pitch and yaw, and we’re trying to recover the roll.

For simplicity, assume that the image plane passes through the origin. To avoid a change of orientation, the unit vector $\mathbf n$ that corresponds to the camera’s axis defines the negative $z'$-axis of the camera coordinate system. Let $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ be a pair of orthogonal unit vectors that define “right” and “up,” respectively for the camera. These two vectors are parallel to the edges of the viewport, so are the ones we’re trying to find. Together with $\mathbf n$ these vectors define the $x'y'z'$ camera coordinate system. They form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^3$ and so are related to the world coordinate system by a rotation. (For a left-handed viewport coordinate system as is common in computer graphics, take $\mathbf n$ as defining the positive $z'$-axis instead.)

[image]

(The image plane is moved away from the world-coordinate origin for clarity.)

Recall that the columns of a transformation matrix are the images of the basis, so the matrix that maps from the camera coordinate system to the world coordinate system has $\mathbf u$, $\mathbf v$ and $-\mathbf n$ as its columns. The inverse of a rotation matrix is its transpose, so the matrix that maps from world coordinates to camera coordinates has these vectors as its *rows*. The projection is therefore given by the matrix product $$P=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}1&0&0\\0&1&0\end{array}\right]\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf u^T\\\mathbf v^T\\-\mathbf n^T\end{bmatrix}=\left[\begin{array}{r}\mathbf u^T\\\mathbf v^T\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}u_x&u_y&u_z\\v_x&v_y&v_z\end{array}\right]=\begin{bmatrix}P\mathbf e_x&P\mathbf e_y&P\mathbf e_z\end{bmatrix}.$$ The last equality highlights the fact that the columns of $P$ are the images of the world-coordinate basis vectors (expressed in viewport coordinates), so $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ can be read directly from the coordinates of these images.

Now, the image plane to screen mapping typically involves some scaling. If the horizontal and vertical scale factors are equal, then you can use the resulting vectors as is or normalize/scale them as needed. Otherwise (e.g., for non-square pixels), you’ll need to retrieve the scale factors from the camera’s intrinsic matrix.

For example, let’s say that with the unit normal in your question, you have for direction vectors of the images of unit world coordinate basis vectors the screen vectors $(18.5907, -3.80073)$, $(6.69494, 15.8854)$, and $(-3.09257, 11.5416)$, respectively. Taking the first coordinates of these vectors we have $(18.5907,6.69494,-3.09257)$, which when normalized is $\mathbf u=(0.929535, 0.334747, -0.154629)$. Similarly, the second coordinates produce $\mathbf v=(-0.190036,0.794268,0.577082)$. If you form the matrix $U=\begin{bmatrix}\mathbf u&\mathbf v&\mathbf n\end{bmatrix}$, you can verify that $U^TU=I$ so that this is an orthonormal set of vectors, and that $\det U=1$, so that it is a right-handed basis. This computation also verifies that for the projection matrix $P$ formed from these vectors, $P\mathbf u=(1,0)$ and $P\mathbf v=(0,1)$, which is what was wanted.

---

This works because of a reciprocity between orthonormal coordinate systems, which itself is a result of the symmetry of inner products. For any basis $\mathscr B=\{\mathbf e_1,\mathbf e_2,\mathbf e_3\}$ of $\mathbb R^3$, the coordinates of a vector $\mathbf v$ are the coefficients of the unique linear combination $\mathbf v=c_1\mathbf e_1+c_2\mathbf e_2+c_3\mathbf e_3$. If the basis is orthonormal, we have $\mathbf v=(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf e_1)\mathbf e_1+(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf e_2)\mathbf e_2+(\mathbf v\cdot\mathbf e_3)\mathbf e_3$, that is, the coordinates of $\mathbf v$ are the scalar projections of $\mathbf v$ onto the basis vectors. If we have another orthonormal basis $\mathscr B'=\{\mathbf e_1',\mathbf e_2',\mathbf e_3'\}$, we have $$\begin{align} \mathbf e_1 &= (\mathbf e_1\cdot\mathbf e_1')\mathbf e_1'+(\mathbf e_1\cdot\mathbf e_2')\mathbf e_2'+(\mathbf e_1\cdot\mathbf e_3')\mathbf e_3' \\ \mathbf e_2 &= (\mathbf e_2\cdot\mathbf e_1')\mathbf e_1'+(\mathbf e_2\cdot\mathbf e_2')\mathbf e_2'+(\mathbf e_2\cdot\mathbf e_3')\mathbf e_3' \\ \mathbf e_3 &= (\mathbf e_3\cdot\mathbf e_1')\mathbf e_1'+(\mathbf e_3\cdot\mathbf e_2')\mathbf e_2'+(\mathbf e_3\cdot\mathbf e_3')\mathbf e_3'.\end{align}$$ At the same time, we also have $$\begin{align} \mathbf e_1' &= (\mathbf e_1'\cdot\mathbf e_1)\mathbf e_1+(\mathbf e_1'\cdot\mathbf e_2)\mathbf e_2+(\mathbf e_1'\cdot\mathbf e_3)\mathbf e_3 \\ \mathbf e_2' &= (\mathbf e_2'\cdot\mathbf e_1)\mathbf e_1+(\mathbf e_2'\cdot\mathbf e_2)\mathbf e_2+(\mathbf e_2'\cdot\mathbf e_3)\mathbf e_3 \\ \mathbf e_3' &= (\mathbf e_3'\cdot\mathbf e_1)\mathbf e_1+(\mathbf e_3'\cdot\mathbf e_2)\mathbf e_2+(\mathbf e_3'\cdot\mathbf e_3)\mathbf e_3.\end{align}$$ Since $\mathbf a\cdot\mathbf b=\mathbf b\cdot\mathbf a$, we can see from the above that the $\mathscr B'$-coordinates of $\mathbf e_1$ are equal to the *first* $\mathscr B$-coordinates of the elements of $\mathscr B'$ and vice-versa, and similarly for the other basis vectors. This reciprocity is what allows us to read the *world* coordinates of $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ from the *viewport/screen* coordinates of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$, above.

Comment: Amd, i am not sure about what you wrote. A projection of n onto the xy-plane gives another vector and that together with n lies in a plane perpendicular to the horizontal of the view screen. That sounds good but the part about cross products of n with coordinate axes like (0,0,1) does not make sense to me since the product would be neither a horizontal or vertical vector.

Comment: @Mark Pay attention to the primes.You’re not projecting onto the $x$-$y$ plane; you’re projecting onto a plane given by the equation $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf r=d$, and I take $d=0$ for simplicity. The vectors $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ lie in this plane and, together with $\mathbf n$, form an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb R^3$, So, you’re projecting onto the $\mathbf u$-$\mathbf v$ plane (which I call $x'$-$y'$) and relative to that basis, the projection consists of dropping the $z'$-coordinate. The two cross products are a simple way to generate $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$.

Comment: ok but where did r come from? That was not talked about initially. Also, what is wrong with just doing it the way i said? You have n and the projection of n onto the xy-plane. Would not a cross product of these two vectors give the horizontal vector? A second cross-product between n and the horizontal gives the vertical vector?

Comment: @Mark $\mathbf r$ is just the variable in the equation of the plane. The plane consists of all vectors $\mathbf r$ that satisfy it.

Comment: @Mark The cross product of any vector and its projection onto the $x$-$y$ plane lies in the $x$-$y$ plane, which is not the plane that you’re projecting onto, so no, this doesn’t give you the horizontal vector. In an extreme case, suppose that $\mathbf n=(0,0,1)$, i.e., you’re looking straight up the $z$-axis. The projection of $\mathbf n$ onto the $x$-$y$ plane is zero, and now you’re stuck.

Comment: @Mark Had a “d’oh moment.” The coordinates of the screen edge direction vectors can be read directly from the basis vector images.

Comment: yes the moment was appropriate but let me give you one as well. What does the question say? Does it say that none of the xyz-frame axes correspond to the view direction? So i appreciate the pointing out of the edge case and the hoops you have to jump to get around it. Hope this clears things up!

Comment: @Mark What hoops? The conditions in your question don’t exclude a normal that coincides with the $z$-axis. That case clearly illustrates that your idea of using the projection of the normal onto the $x$-$y$ plane can’t be right. in the correct solution, there’s nothing special about that or any other orientation of the camera axis.

Comment: oh yes that is correct. I should have said that none where aligned to the screen and view direction. But I still appreciate all the things you wrote when the edge case happens.

Comment: Honestly, I still am having trouble seeing what you are doing. I get the part about you projecting the green (Y) and red (X) axis onto the plane of the monitor screen. The green (Y) axis does move away from you. So it is pointing ahead of you or like you say towards the "bottom."  This gives us "image" axes X' and Y' on the plane of the monitor. The part after that just make no intuitive or geometric sense to me. If you where going to explain this without matrix math then how would you do it?

Comment: @Mark No, it’s because the $z'$-axis—the camera’s axis—points away from the viewer that there’s a change of orientation. It doesn’t seem like you’re getting that part, either. The short, facile explanation of what I’m doing is that I’m simply reading the answer from the coordinates of $X$, $Y$ and $Z$.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I will study your solution more but did another approach that worked with some added info i did not previously have. Basically i got the initial "up" or vertical direction (0,1,0) in the view when the camera was in it's initial orientation. The software i use then also provides the new camera orientation as a quaternion which i use to get the new vertical direction. After that it is just a cross-product of this vertical with the camera's view direction for the horizontal direction. But if what you does works then i want to know it as well. Thanks again!

Comment: @Mark That’s a variation on the cross product $\mathbf n\times\mathbf u$ that I had in an earlier version. Doing that is very easy, of course, but makes your entire question moot since you’re not starting from the projected image any more.

Comment: I tried both your procedure of mapping xyz-frame axis ends onto the view plane and did not get u and v parallel with the edges of the screen. Also, I just used the values you gave for u (0.929535,0.334747,−0.154629) and v (−0.190036,0.794268,0.577082), which also did not work. Both gave basically the same wrong result. They are in the view plane but they are not orthogonal and they have the wrong orientation. What did I/we miss???

Comment: @Mark I have no way of knowing what you missed, since all you’ve told me is that it didn’t work. Remember that because of roundoff and other numerical errors, things that should be zero mathematically often end up being very small numbers instead. Similarly, things that should be $1$ end up being slightly different from $1$. E.g., $\mathbf u\cdot\mathbf v\approx1.04358e-7$, which is effectively zero since there are only 6 digits of precision in the input values.

Comment: This is not slightly different. My results and your results for u and v are basically the same. But both are not even close on the screen. The horizontal is about 10 degrees off and the vertical is about 20 degrees off.

Comment: I checked all of those and it maps points onto the normal plane but i will check again. The funny thing is that your values do exactly the same thing. I will post the pictures.

Comment: @Mark :shrug: My example was taken from real data that was designed to match your illustration. I’ve also tested it against quite a few random projections. It works, both mathematically and in practice. If it’s not working for you, then I recommend that you check whatever it is that you’ve got against the assumptions I’ve used and adjust accordingly. It could be something as simple as not compensating for a shifted screen origin, or not really having an orthographic projection after all. At any rate, I’ve already spent way too much time on this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I will look more????

Comment: What fixes the orientation of u and v in the view plane? I can see how the math might work (reciprocity, symmetry of inner products, etc) once these axis orientations on the view plane are known but I cannot see this working to get these orientations unless more orientation information is given. Possibly either an axis u or an axis v direction.

Comment: @Mark $\mathbf u$ and $\mathbf v$ are inherent in the mapping from the world coordinates of the image plane to screen coordinates. This mapping is part of the cascade of transformations that form the total projection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60425/discussion-between-mark-and-amd).

Comment: Not enough information is provided to fix the orientation of the views frame. It is well known that you need at minimum three non-colinear points of a rigid body to describe it's position and orientation. For the view frame you only have two, those would be any two on the line of the view direction. This line is like an axis and the rigid body, in our case the view frame, can still rotate around that axis. A third non-colinear point or simlar information like an angle of rotation or another axis of the frame, will fix the view frames position. The problem cannot be solved as stated.

Comment: @Mark Rubbish. In your example image you have displayed not only three, but four nonclolinear points of a rigid body—that of the pyramidn formed by the world coordinate axis vectors. The fact that you have a screen image at all means that something along the way has fixed a coordinate system for the image plane. A choice *has* been made for the amount of rotation about the view axis—the camera’s roll—and that choice is implicit in the mapping that produces a screen image. Prying that implicit choice out is a then matter of quite elementary coordinate transformation calculations.

Comment: One rigid body with 3non-colinear points is the xyz-frame. The other rigid body is the uvn-frame but you only have two points for it. So you cannot move the xyz-frame into the same placement as the uvn-frame. There is not enough information.

Comment: @Mark There are 6 degrees of freedom in an orthographic projection, seven if you include a scale factor when going from world to screen coordinates. The four points pictured on screen provide eight constraints, *and* you say that you have the normal to the image plane. That’s more than enough information to recover the entire transformation. It’s clear that you’re not going to be convinced, however, so I’m not going to waste any more of my time trying to do so.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not convinced on either your theory and i not convinced for empirical reasons. The data does not fit.

Comment: @Mark Occam's razor might suggest that the scant (practically no) empirical data you’ve provided here reveals a systematic error in your application of both solutions, or that you’ve misstated the problem in the first place. Since you’ve yet to provided a concrete example, there’s no way to know.

Comment: Well, you got Occam's razor wrong as well. It say basically not to use more conceptual entities than necessary. I used less theory than you. Mine is that your ideas are wrong and that fits the data. You do not even make a good theoretical/ conceptual case. If this isn't your idea but is known by others then you should not have a hard time referencing works that deal with this problem. Cite something so we can all check. Believe me when I say that I am not the only one that thinks you stuff does not work. So prove us wrong because we are very skeptical.